# Show out of stock products at the end of product search results page

Tags: magento-enterprise, products, search, out-of-stock

I want to `show out of stock products` at the end of product search results page. I have `tried to do that by using some free extension/code` but none of code didn't worked for search results page. please suggest me how can I do that.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if solution isn't very clean. I just copied from one of the modules which has been written many years ago...

etc/config.xml

```
        <catalog_product_collection_load_before>
            <observers>
                <product_sort>
                     <type>singleton</type>
                     <class>custom/observer</class>
                     <method>catalogProductSort</method>
                </product_sort>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_collection_load_before>
```

Observer method:

```
public function catalogProductSort($observer) {
    $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();

    if ( !($collection instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection)
        || !Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_CatalogInventory')
    ) {
        return ;
    }

    $allowedClasses = array(
        'Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection',
        'Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext_Collection',
        'Activo_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext',
    );
    if ( !in_array( get_class($collection), $allowedClasses) ) {
        return ;
    }

    $collection->joinField('is_in_stock',
        'cataloginventory/stock_item',
        'is_in_stock',
        'product_id=entity_id',
        '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
        'left');

    $select = $collection->getSelect();
    $orders = $select->order( 'is_in_stock '.Zend_Db_Select::SQL_DESC)
            ->getPart('order');
    array_unshift($orders, array_pop($orders));
    $select->setPart('order',$orders);
}
```